# Preventing popup from opening on load, Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

my question is quite simple I guess, even though I cannot seem to be able to adress the problem. I am using some iframes and as I made this into a wordpress page template instead of pure html, the pop-up on the page has started popping as soon as the page loads. How do I prevent this?

Thank you!

**Page template:**

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Klasseforside
*/
?>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3171189/Klassekampen/klassekampen.css" />

    </head>
    <body class="iframe" style="background-color:transparent; background-image:none; position:relative;">


<div >
<div >
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
<div>
<h2 style="margin-bottom:-20px; margin-left:47px;" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></h2>
<?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this page »</p>'); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see any popup in this code (?).

Comment: This is the page template, the content is placed in the actual page -I have forgot to provide the link though: http://ungdomsvaern.dk/klasserne/test/

Comment: Please, post all relevant code in the Question itself ([edit]).